# jQuery intro to syntax and having a syntax error

Tags: jquery

Hello I am just starting the CodeCademy program on jQuery. One of the very first assignments is just asking me to 'call' on a function called ".ready". I am apparently having some sort of syntax error as I keep getting the response "Oops, try again. Did you put document inside $() ?" I know its insanely simple but I have zero jQuery knowledge and am really stuck here. Thanks guys

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
$(document).ready();
```

Comment: Remove that fourth line and add the code you want to call in the second line

Comment: You are calling `ready` *twice* here. Why? I also recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: thanks @FelixKling I was thinking the first line was defining the function but that must be unnecessary in jQuery which i should have realized. and thank you for a great reference to help me out!

Comment: The first line calls `ready` and passes a function to it. The second line calls `ready` and doesn't pass anything to it.

Comment: @FelixKling _"The first line calls ready and passes a function to it. The second line calls ready and doesn't pass anything to it"_ This should not cause an `error` ; `.ready()` returns `this` . Message _"Oops, try again. Did you put document inside $() ?"_ appear to be generated by program submitting jQuery inside of ?

Comment: @guest271314: I'm not claiming that this causes the "error". It's not a runtime or syntax error anyway. I don't know how Codeacadamy validates the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function `ready()` twice.
The first time, you are also calling a `handler`, which is going to execute once the DOM is ready.
You can also see how the `ready()` function works [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to any "syntax error" at `js` at Question. The response

> "Oops, try again. Did you put document inside $() ?"

seems to be a notification message generated by the program submitting `js` in.

---

[`jQuery.fn.ready()`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.ready) simply returns `this` ; if function passed as parameter , calls function passed . See also `jQuery.ready` , `jQuery.isReady` , `jQuery.readyWait`

```
function (fn) {
    // Add the callback
    jQuery.ready.promise().done(fn);

    return this;
}
```

```js
window.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log(e)
}

$(document).ready(function() {

});

console.log($(document).ready()
            , $("body").ready()
            , $("body").ready().find("span").text()
           );

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert($("span").text())
});

$("body").ready(function() {
  alert($("span").text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span>abc</span>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sgmhv3a8/